# Getting lambda to generate unique data in a loop

Tags: python, lambda, blender

I'm working on an add-on for Blender, and I'm trying to assign a custom update function to a list of properties through an "update" attribute. The update function will only accept 2 parameters (self and context, or s and c). But I want to send a third parameter that identifies which property is being updated. This parameter is an index. This is what I started with:

```
for i in range(0,len(props)):
    props[i].update = lambda s, c: CustomUpdate( s, c, i )
```

But I soon realized that lambda records the variable being used, rather than the value of that variable. So all of the property update functions end up being generated like this:

```
for i in range(0,len(props)):
    props[i].update = CustomUpdate( s, c, len(props) - 1 )
```

I looked for answers and found this solution:

```
for i in range(0,len(props)):
    props[i].update = lambda s, c, index=i: CustomUpdate( s, c, index )
```

However, Blender appears to be double checking the number of parameters for the function supplied here, and throws an error when more than 2 are used, so I can't use a third lambda parameter.

So I'm currently trying to figure out how to convince the lambda to generate a unique index for each property for the callback. Possibly some way to edit the lambda after assigning it? Or any trick to wrap `i` in some code to force evaluation during parsing instead of during execution?

Edit: Forgot to mention that my list of props is static. So the loop index counter could be unrolled by the parser, if such a thing is possible.

Comment: I wish someone would make a simpler version of this problem/answer for the less initiated. I doubt most new programmers will even know what a closure is. It will be difficult for them to locate that page when they run into this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each lambda needs its own context to hold its value of i:

```
def makeLambda(i):
    return lambda s,c: CustomUpdate( s, c, i )
for i in range(0,len(props)):
    prop[i].update = makeLambda(i)
```

Comment: Why doesn't lambda make it's own context? I would have expected it to make a closure 'recording' the values of `i`.

Comment: I guess this answers my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2295368/1011724. Interesting.

Comment: There's nothing to close over; the `for` loop doesn't define a new local scope.

Comment: I just tested it. It works. You have saved my week. Thanks man

Comment: (Or put another way, it's a "closure" over the global scope, but the `for` loop continuously changes the value of `i` in that scope.)

Comment: Another (similar) approach would be `prop[i].update = partial(lambda s,c: CustomUpdate( s, c, i ), i)`

Comment: @Dan Not quite; the `i` in the lambda is still a free variable; all you've done is created a callable which uses the current value of `i` as the `s` argument for `CustomUpdate`.

Comment: @chepner Oops, typo `prop[i].update = partial(lambda i, s, c: CustomUpdate(s, c, i ), i)`